# Coordinates of an external named reference

Tags: google-sheets

In [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TBLF4H6r7EpCBtbTaa9Yan986DnyC_7UhDIWAG5gQX8/edit#gid=0), I've got a column named range: `Sheet1!I:I`, named `NamedRanged1`.

In [another sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FRm5X9jtnd7fIwOy5eBM69le5SArn9Qg6DAdeGcfOYw/edit#gid=0), I'd like to **get the index of that named range**, i.e., 9 (`I` is 9th column).

I tried with [`ADDRESS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) and [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en):

```
=ADDRESS(IMPORTRANGE("1TBLF4H6r7EpCBtbTaa9Yan986DnyC_7UhDIWAG5gQX8","Sheet1!A1:Z100"))
```

but without success.

Is there a [function](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411) which can retrieve coordinates from the name of a named reference?

Comment: Try this formula: `ADDRESS(ROW(Book1!NamedRanged1), COLUMN(Book1!NamedRanged1)) & ":" &
ADDRESS(ROWS(Book1!NamedRanged1)+(ROW(Book1!NamedRanged1)-1), COLUMNS(Book1!NamedRanged1)+(COLUMN(Book1!NamedRanged1)-1))`.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in function to get the address of a named range from another spreadsheet but you could build a script by using [Google Apps Script](http://google.com/script/start) / [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

The following script will add the address of a named range from an external spreadsheet to the active cell

```
function demo() {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TBLF4H6r7EpCBtbTaa9Yan986DnyC_7UhDIWAG5gQX8/edit#gid=0';
  var name = 'NamedRange1';
  NAMEDRANGEADDRESS(url,name);
}

function NAMEDRANGEADDRESS(url,name) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var rng = ss.getRangeByName(name);
    var address = rng.getA1Notation();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(address);
}
```

For detailed instructions about how to create your first script checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview.